# Função .split() bugando a saída da string no python2, como resolver?

Tags: python, string, lista, split

Olá, sou novo em Python e minha dúvida pode ser óbvia, mas gostaria de entender melhor o funcionamento da manipulação de `string`; Estou me deparando com um erro de execução de uma função que criei e não entendo o comportamento da string deste caso.A função retira de cada variável da lista "dados" os espaços em branco e o texto após a identificação de um caractere específico ("#") usando a função `.split()`, `.strip()` e `.index()`, restando somente a primeira parte, sem espaços, de cada elemento da lista (usando [s:]), cujo valor é retornado pela função.

Segue o código:

```
arquivo = "treee; hpot #NomesEspecificos"
tipo = "30;40;10 #Numeros Especificos"
arq = "tritrem; bitrem; rodotrem #VehicleNamesIn"

dados = [tipol,arq,arquivo,tipo]

def separador(s):
    s = ''.join(s.split(' '))
    tail = s[s.index('#'):]
    head = s.strip(tail)
    return head

dados2=[separador(s) for s in dados] 
print(dados2)
```

Após execução, este código retorna:

```
['2168', 'tritrem;bitrem;rodotr', 'treee;hpot', '30;40;10']
```

Mas deveria retornar:

```
['2168', 'tritrem;bitrem;rodotrem', 'treee;hpot', '30;40;10']
```

Já fiz algumas alterações na formação das strings para alcançar este resultado demonstrado, mas se rodar a variável "arquivo" com a seguinte alteração:

```
arquivo = "treee;hpot #CraneNameInput"
```

Irá resultar no mesmo erro identificado na saída da variável "arq":

```
['2168', 'tritrem;bitrem;rodotr', ';hpo', '30;40;10']
```

Gostaria de entender o motivo deste desvio e, se possível, uma solução para este problema. Confesso que já tentei muita coisa e ainda não resolvi. Valeu pessoal.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código não está fazendo chamadas muito convencionais, e há formas mais consistentes e curtas de fazer o que você quer.

O problema que você está tendo é que você está usando o método `.strip` de strings, para remover o sufixo - só que o `strip` **não leva em conta a ordem dos caracteres** - ele simplesmente remove - dos dois lados da string, todos os caracteres que estiverem na lista, independente da ordem. Então, como no seu exemplo, o sufixo inclui os caracteres "e" e "m", esses estão sendo removidos junto com o restante.

Na verdade, o método comum para separar "antes e depois de um dado caractere" é justamente o `.split()` - e a parte maluca é que você também está usando esse método, só que para um propósito que não é o dele. O normal para se remover todas as ocorrências de um dado caractere em uma string é usar o método `.replace`, e não um `.join` em cima de um `.split`. (Do jeito que está feito no entanto, apesar de menos eficiente, mais difícil de ler, etc... o resultado é o esperado).

Portanto, sua função pode ser simplesmente:

```
def separador(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', '')
    return s.split('#')[0]
```

Comment: Ótima explicação, estou começando em Python e sua resposta contribuiu muito, já estou corrigindo todo meu código. Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Você pode querer dar uma olhada na documentação dos métodos disponíveis  para string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

(nota: tem tanta coisa, entre chamadas legadas criadas décadas atrás, e coisas relativamente novas como `.casefold` que ninguém sabe tudo decor, nem faz sentido - mas é legal dar uma lida pra saber o que já existe pronto)